# Finding max sum sub list and sum with divide and conquer

Tags: python, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

So I'm trying to print the max sum as well as its corresponding sub list, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get its sub list. Here's my code so far using python that only returns the max sum:

```
full = [7,-1,1,2,-8,1]
indices = []

def sumHelper(listnum, a, z):
    if a == z:
        global indices
        return listnum[a]
    mid = (a+z)//2
    return max(sumHelper(listnum,a,mid),sumHelper(listnum,mid+1,z),straddleSum(listnum,a,mid,z))


def straddleSum(listnum, a, m, z):
    right = -(2**31)-1
    left = -(2**31)-1
    count = 0
    for i in range(m,a-1,-1):
        count = count + listnum[i]
        if count > left:
            left = count

    count = 0
    for i in range(m+1,z+1):
        count = count + listnum[i]
        if count > right:
            right = count

    return right + left

print(sumHelper(full, 0, len(full)-1))
print(indices)
```

Comment: Any example i/p and expected o/p?

Comment: input: [7,-1,1,2,-8,1]
output: 9 [7 -1 1 2]

Comment: Hi @catpuccino, please edit your code so it is clearer. Some things in strsddleSum: is the for loop(s)  part of the function or not. If they are please indent the code appropriately. On a different note,  in sumHelper, you have global indices, however you do not do anything with it in any of the functions.. better to pull it out if that is the case. Even if you were manipulating indices, the saner approach will be to pass it as an argument to the function that needs it.

Answer (score 2):

You are only returning the sum of a range. To get the range as well, simply return a tuple of sum and range instead of just the sum: `return listnum[a], (a,z)`. Then give `max` a key function so it only uses the sum from the tuple to find maximum range `key= lambda x: x[0]`.

```
full = [7,-1,1,2,-8,1]
# full = [-1,-2,-3,-4]
# full = [1,2,-100,3,4]
indices = []

def sumHelper(listnum, a, z):
    if a == z:
        global indices

        # return sum of range and it's left and right index
        return listnum[a], (a,z)
    mid = (a+z)//2
    return max(sumHelper(listnum,a,mid),sumHelper(listnum,mid+1,z),straddleSum(listnum,a,mid,z), key= lambda x: x[0])


def straddleSum(listnum, a, m, z):
    right = -(2**31)-1
    left = -(2**31)-1

    lpos = rpos= None   # left and right index of max range

    count = 0
    for i in range(m,a-1,-1):
        count = count + listnum[i]
        if count > left:
            left = count
            lpos = i

    count = 0
    for i in range(m+1,z+1):
        count = count + listnum[i]
        if count > right:
            right = count
            rpos = i

    # return sum of range and it's left and right index
    return right + left, (lpos, rpos)

msum, msumb_range = sumHelper(full, 0, len(full)-1)
print(msum)
print(msumb_range)
```